# JLine2: Is it a bug in completion mechanism or not?

Tags: java, jline

Here is my Java code.

```
public class CompletionTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ConsoleReader console = new ConsoleReader();
        Completer nil = new NullCompleter();
        Completer read = new StringsCompleter("read");
        Completer and = new StringsCompleter("and");
        Completer save = new StringsCompleter("save");
        Completer aggregator = new AggregateCompleter(
                new ArgumentCompleter(read, and, save, nil)
        );
        console.addCompleter(aggregator);
        while (console.readLine() != null) {
            console.println();
        }
    }
}
```

If I complete an input like in the snippet below

```
read an[TAB]d
```

and then go back to set the cursor to

```
read a[cursor is here]nd
```

and press TAB, I get not expected completion

```
read and d
```

Is it a bug or expected behavior of JLine2 library?